# Specify the git branch code to be deployed in Elastic Beanstalk environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Is there any way to specify which git branch code to be deployed to an Elastic Beanstalk environment?

Assume, I have two git branches named **test** and **stage** and I have an Elastic Beanstalk environment named **test-env**.

Now, I set the branch defaults in `config.yml` as below:

```
branch-defaults: 
  test:
    environment: test-env
    group_suffix: null
global:
  application_name: test
  default_ec2_keyname: abcde
  default_platform: Ruby 2.2 (Puma)
  default_region: us-west-2
  profile: eb-cli
  sc: git
```

Now, what I need is if I deploy from **stage** branch with `eb deploy test-env` it should automatically deploy the code from **test** branch or it should throw an error..

Is there any way to do it. If no please suggest me some other way to do it..

Thanks..

Answer (score 6):

This isn't something that the EB CLI supports; it will always run a deployment from the current branch. However, it's certainly something you can script (I'm assuming you're running under `bash`, it wouldn't be too hard to port to Windows command shell using the `for` command to extract the current branch name):

deployTest.sh:

```
#!bin/bash
# Grab the current branch name
current=`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`
# Just in case we have any in-flight work, stash it
git stash
# Switch to 'test' branch
git checkout test
# Deploy to  test-env
eb deploy test-env
# Switch back to whatever branchwe were on
git checkout $current
# Restore in-flight work
git stash pop
```